# How to avoid file download, if the file is already present in my local with html/javascript

Tags: html

How to avoid file download, if the file is already present in my local.

My Code:
<
  a href="file:///C:/Users/t_smrithik/Desktop/DNS.cap">DNS.cap

I do not want to download this file again. I just want to open it. The file gets downloaded to a temp folder and then the Wireshark app(app used to open cap files) loads it.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript** cannot access the filesystem and check for existence. The only interaction with the filesystem is with loading js files and images (png/gif/etc).

**Javascript is not the task for this**